# Disclosure button initially hidden, then visible

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want the disclosure button to be visible on each of the items of the list only when i click an "EDIT" button. How can i do that?? I tried "list.setOnItemDisclosure(true);" on clicking the EDIT button but disclosure didn't appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a css class where the x-item-disclosure would be hidden :

```
.hidden-disclosure-list .x-list-disclosure {
  display: none;
}
```

Then when you want to hide them you just have to do:

```
list.addCls('hidden-disclosure-list');
```

And when you want to display them just do:

```
list.removeCls('hidden-disclosure-list');
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Manipulate the list's on item disclosure property...On click of the edit button toggle the list's onItemDisclosure property...

```
list.setOnItemDisclosure(true);
```